Java connection with proxy 403 captcha, but System.setProperty() work. Why?
I need work proxy with Multithreading.
But my connection (HttpURLConnection or Okhttp) don't work with proxy, it's response 403 bad.
This code response 200 OK:

`    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myProxy");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "myPort");`

But I need different proxy for every thread later, and I use Okhttp, and it's don't work with proxy (response 403 bad + captcha "I am not robot")
Please, help me! Why System.setProperty() work 200 OK without captcha, but I use the same proxy in Okhttp - don't work 403 + captcha "I am not robot" ?
How can I do it? Eventually I need separate different proxy for every separate connection (thread).
`    Proxy proxy2 = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("35.185.196.38", 3128));
    URL url2 = new URL("example.com");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .proxy(proxy2)
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .build();
    
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url2)
    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
                    .build();

    try(Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {            
                Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(response));
                Document doc21 = Jsoup.parse(response.body().string());
    
                System.out.println(doc2);
                System.out.println(doc21);
    
            }`

This code 403 bad response:
`<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=https://example.com/siteDo/11278032}
 </body>
</html>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <style>*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}html  --- A LOT OF LETTERS --- }div:nth-child(3){animation-delay:-.15s}@keyframes lds-ring{0%{transform:rotate(0)}to{transform:rotate(1turn)}}@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast:active),screen and (-ms-high-contrast:none){.main-wrapper,body{display:block}}</style>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="375">
 </head>
 <body class="no-js">
  <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
   <div class="main-content">
    <noscript>
     <div id="challenge-error-title">
      <div class="h2">
       <span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </noscript>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '3',cZone: "example.com",cType: 'managed',cNounce: '32550',cRay: --- A LOT OF LETTERS ---  }}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());</script>
 </body>
</html>`

